# Dirac field charge conjugation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices, charge-conjugation

I struggled a bit to understand the proof of the relation $C\overline\psi\psi C=\overline\psi\psi$ in Peskin's and Schroeder's book *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* (page 70, formula 3.147):
$$C\overline\psi\psi C=\ldots=-(\gamma^0)_{ab}(\gamma^2)_{bc}\psi_c\overline\psi_d(\gamma^0)_{de}(\gamma^2)_{ea}=\overline\psi_d(\gamma^0)_{de}(\gamma^2)_{ea}(\gamma^0)_{ab}(\gamma^2)_{bc}\psi_c.$$
They say that in the last step the minus sign comes from fermion anticommutation.

As far as I can see we can't merely get it from $\{\psi_c,\overline\psi_d\}=0$, because this equality is false. Based on my calculation we have
$$\{\psi_c,\overline\psi_d\}=\{\psi_c,\psi_e^{\dagger}(\gamma^0)_{ed}\}=\{\psi_c,\psi_e^{\dagger}\}(\gamma^0)_{ed}=\delta_{ce}(\gamma^0)_{ed}=(\gamma^0)_{cd}.$$
So we have
$$\psi_c\overline\psi_d=-\overline\psi_d\psi_c+(\gamma^0)_{cd}.$$
Using this result we have
$$C\overline\psi\psi C=\ldots=-(\gamma^0)_{ab}(\gamma^2)_{bc}\psi_c\overline\psi_d(\gamma^0)_{de}(\gamma^2)_{ea}=-(\gamma^0)_{ab}(\gamma^2)_{bc}\left[-\overline\psi_d\psi_c+(\gamma^0)_{cd}\right](\gamma^0)_{de}(\gamma^2)_{ea}=(\gamma^0)_{ab}(\gamma^2)_{bc}\overline\psi_d\psi_c(\gamma^0)_{de}(\gamma^2)_{ea}-(\gamma^0)_{ab}(\gamma^2)_{bc}(\gamma^0)_{cd}(\gamma^0)_{de}(\gamma^2)_{ea}$$
Now, the second term is null:
$$-(\gamma^0)_{ab}(\gamma^2)_{bc}(\gamma^0)_{cd}(\gamma^0)_{de}(\gamma^2)_{ea}=-\left(\gamma^0\gamma^2\gamma^0\gamma^0\gamma^2\right)_{aa}=(\gamma^0)_{aa}=0,$$
where I used $\gamma^0\gamma^0=1$, $\gamma^2\gamma^2=-1$, and $(\gamma^0)_{aa}=0$, because, irrespective of the respresentation,  $\textrm{tr}\,(\gamma^0)=0$.
Since the second term is null I have got the last step in the book.

My calculation is a little more elaborate than what the authors' comment seems to imply, so I wonder if I'm making some mistakes or I'm missing something that makes the calculation more immediate.

Comment: I do not have P&S to hand, but usually in these  calculations we are thinking of path integral fomulation where $\bar \psi$ and $\psi$ are *independent* anticommuting c-numbers. In that context $\bar\psi$ is *not* equal to  $\psi^\dagger \gamma_0$ and  $\{ \bar\psi_a,\psi_b\}$ *is* equal to zero.

Comment: Path integral formulation is introduced much later in the book, so I'd say it can't be that